# autofac webapi integration RegisterApiControllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

Doesn't `RegisterApiControllers`'s extension method register `ApiController` with parameter in the constructor?

My code doesn't work like many examples show

[Application_start]

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Coso>().As<ICoso>().InstancePerRequest();  //register my type
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());  //register controller with autofac WebApi2 integration
var container = builder.Build();
var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);  //set the webapi dependecy resolver
```

[Controller]

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public ValuesController(ICoso coso)
    { 

    }

    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

Error:

> no parameter less constructor defined for this object

Comment: That should work. Where do you host your controllers?

Comment: further details:

project template: **VS2013**,

target framework: **NET 4.5.1**,

<package id="Autofac" version="**3.5.0**" targetFramework="net45" />,

<package id="Autofac.WebApi2" version="**3.4.0**" 
targetFramework="net45" />,


ASIDE NOTE: the project contains the StartUp.cs class.

Should i consider it a **mvc5(owin)** project and not a simple **mvc4 with WebApi** project?

Comment: MaKCblMKo - into the standard "Controllers" folder of the project

Comment: I think the question was if it is the same assembly

Comment: If you use OWIN in your app, then you missed some configuration of autofac middleware.

Comment: I'd be interested to see the StartUp.cs class